# Writing where clause for Feature Class To Feature Class in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, feature-class, where-clause

The following picture shows the table for the shapefile.
I need to extract those rows with different values of TotalCT, which means I need to extract the first row into a new shapefile named Value_1.shp, and extract the second and third rows into another new shapefile named Value_2.shp. I wrote the below code, but it gave me the empty shapefiles. Any suggestions? 
[image]

```
casefile = r"C:\Users\TL\Desktop\831test\913\FULLNAME_Atlanta_Park_Rd.shp"
outputfolder = r"C:\Users\TL\Desktop\831test\casefile"
ValueCT = unique_values(casefile, field)
i = 1
field = "TotalCT"
for value in ValueCT:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(casefile, outputfolder, 'Value_' + str(i), "TotalCT" + "= %d" % value)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a `print('Value_' + str(i), "TotalCT" + "= %d" % value)` to see what it is passing for the where clause?

Comment: Thank a bunch! I did what your suggest and noticed that the %d force the values to integer rather than float. However, there are still problems, and I can't get what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(casefile, outputfolder, 'Value_' + str(i), "TotalCT" + "= %d" % value)
```

perhaps try:

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(casefile, outputfolder, 'Value_{0}'.format(i), "TotalCT = {0}".format(value))
```

The way that I have suggested uses the [Python str.format() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format) which I prefer to its predecessor.